# WebView combobox different dropdown behaviour

Tags: android, webview, combobox

I'm trying to use WebView to append an html code.
I have a default style for comboboxes as below:

```
border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 11px; font-weight: normal; min-width: 123px; width: 123px;
```

In different versions of android dropdown view is not the same.
In my Nexus 5 (kitkat 4.4.2) dropdown view looks like spinner popup selection. But in some of galaxy tabs which they use 4.2.2, dropdown view will be in the bottom of the screen with "next","Prev" and "Done" button.
Is there anyway to have popup selection in 4.2.2 (and below)?